# javascript : JSON obj not coming

Tags: javascript, ajax

What is the issue in below script.Here alert "33here" is coming but am not getting my json object.`alert(jsontext)` is coming blank.if i hit this URL in browser then i am getting JSON object.

```
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("application/json");  
    alert('11here');
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://<hostname>/appsuite/api/login", true );
    alert('22here');
    alert(xmlHttp);
    xmlHttp.send();
    alert('33here');
    var jsontext= xmlHttp.responseText;

    alert(jsontext);
```

Tried as per suggestions but not working.I am new in javascript / ajax.Any issue in this ?

```
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("application/json");  
    alert('Hi 11here');
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://<hostname>/appsuite/api/login", true );
    alert('Hi 22here');
    alert(xmlHttp);
    xmlHttp.send();
    alert('Hi 33here');
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You need a callback.

Comment: @SLaks : plz let me know how to solve it...is this something like : if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
  {
  var jsontext= xmlHttp.responseText;
  }

Comment: Try putting the `.onreadystatechange` code before the `.send()` line

Comment: @Ian : No, I have tried it.alert(xmlHttp.responseText); is not coming.  :(

Comment: @Ian : If i remove "xmlHttp.status == 200" from if condition then alert is coming but its blank.On the other hand, if i hit this URL then i get 200 OK JSON object ( saw in wireshark ).

Comment: Then put `alert(xmlHttp.status);` in the remaining if statement

Comment: xmlHttp.status getting 0. Means response is empty. But if i hit th URL from browser then getting 200 OK. Verified from wireshark tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax runs *asynchronously*.  You can't depend on when the request from `.open` will complete or even *if* it will complete.  Any code that depends on the value of an ajax request **must** be done in the request callback.

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.I have tried and added the same in question above.Its not working (alert(xmlHttp.responseText);  is not coming ).Plz suggest.

Comment: @VJS are you doing a cross domain request?

Comment: cross domain means.url is http://172.20.x.x/appsuite/api/login and 172.x.x.x is reachable from my system.Getting JSON from browser.

Comment: If i remove "xmlHttp.status == 200" from if condition then alert is coming but its blank.On the other hand, if i hit this URL then i get 200 OK JSON object ( saw in wireshark ).

Comment: @VJS do you know what the response code is from the ajax request?

Comment: xmlHttp.status getting 0. Means response is empty. But if i hit th URL from browser then getting 200 OK. Verified from wireshark tool.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is looking at the examples provided by MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

```
function alertContents(httpRequest) {
  try {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
     if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
     } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
   catch( e ) {
     alert('Caught Exception: ' + e.description);
  }
}
```

After the request status reached 200 and the ready state is 4 the response is filled.

Comment: I have tried and added the same in question above.Its not working (alert(xmlHttp.responseText); is not coming ).Plz suggest.